# How to determine if two events are independent when dealing a 5-card hand?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, independence

Let's assume we have a standard deck of 52 cards. A dealt hand will be 5 cards. Consider the following probabilities:

P(dealt at least 1 ace)
P(dealt no 2s)
P(dealt at least 1 ace AND dealt no 2s) = P(dealt at least 1 ace) * P(dealt no 2s)???

Are these independent events? My hunch is that these are dependent events because if I get dealt at least 1 ace, then there are only 4 cards left, which affects the probability of P(dealt no 2s). Normally P(dealt no 2s) would be calculated like so:

$${48 \choose 5} \div {52 \choose 5}$$

But if we open at least 1 ace, then we would have to choose 4, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the set $A$ of all possible hands that do not contain any twos.

Now consider all possible hands that do not contain any twos and also do not contain any aces. Let $B$ be the set of all such hands.

Then $B$ is a subset of $A.$ And if you remove all hands in $B$ from the set $A,$ what is left is a set of hands that do not contain any twos, but every hand contains at least one ace. 
This remaining set is denoted $A \setminus B.$

We can count the number of hands in the set $A$:
$\lvert A\rvert = \binom{48}{5}.$
The number of hands in $B$ is $\lvert B\rvert = \binom{44}{5}.$
Since $B$ is a subset of $A,$ we can find the number of hands in
$A \setminus B$ by setting 
$\lvert A \setminus B\rvert = \lvert A\rvert - \lvert B\rvert
= \binom{48}{5} - \binom{44}{5}.$

So the probability to have at least one ace, but no twos, is
$$
P_1 = \frac{\binom{48}{5} - \binom{44}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}
$$

whereas the probability of at least one ace is 
$\binom{48}{5}/\binom{52}{5},$
the probability of no twos is 
$1 - \binom{48}{5}/\binom{52}{5},$
and the product of the two probabilities is
$$
P_2 = \frac{\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}
\left(1 - \frac{\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}\right).
$$

If you correctly compare these quantities,
then you will find that $P_1$ is slightly greater that $P_2.$
It may help with the comparison if you rewrite each of the quantities as follows:
\begin{align}
P_1 &= \frac{\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}} 
         - \frac{1}{\binom{52}{5}} \binom{44}{5}, \\
P_2 &= \frac{\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}} 
         - \frac{1}{\binom{52}{5}}
             \left(\frac{\binom{48}{5}^2}{\binom{52}{5}}\right).
\end{align}
Then you just need to show that 
$\frac{\binom{48}{5}^2}{\binom{52}{5}} > \binom{44}{5}.$
After a few more cancellations of common factors, this comes down to
$$
\frac{(48\cdot47\cdot46\cdot45\cdot44)^2}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48}
 > 44\cdot43\cdot42\cdot41\cdot40,
$$
which is true because in general, $(n+4)^2 > n(n+8).$

Comment: +1. But "work out these quantities so that you can compare them" sounds to me as if one would first simplify the expressions individually before comparing them; whereas in this case the efficient way to compare them would be to note that they share a term and the denominator, so we only need to compare $\binom{44}5$ to $\frac{\binom{48}5^2}{\binom{52}5}$.

Comment: @joriki This just goes to show the hazard of having tools like Wolfram Alpha available: one can get lazy. I've incorporated your hint into the answer and find that it actually is not necessary to do much numeric calculation at all. Also, thanks for finding and fixing that typo.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, these are dependent events. Let $A$ be the event of getting at least one ace, $B$ - getting no $2$'s. Then,
$$
\mathbb{P}[A] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[\text{not } A] 
              = 1 - \binom{48}{5} \div \binom{52}{5}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{P}[B] = \binom{48}{5} \div \binom{52}{5},
$$
but can you compute $\mathbb{P}[A \cap B]$?

Comment: So it would be something like $P(A) \times P(B|A)$, but this is only calculating if event A occurs before event B. So this probability seems to be a lot tougher to calculate because then we would also need to calculate the inverse of that $P(B \cap A)$

How would we calculate P(dealt at least 1 ace & dealt no 2s)?